# AjaxFileUpload cancelUpload() not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using a AjaxFilUpload from the Ajax Control toolkit in my webform.  I want to check for file size and cancelUpload if it has exceeded a certain size.  I've tried it in OnClientUploadStart & OnClientUploadComplete, but after doing so the file still shows Uploaded on the page.

Webform:

```
<div>
  <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart" 
  OnClientUploadCompleteAll="onUploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadComplete="onUploadComplete" OnClientUploadStart="onUploadStart" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function onUploadStart(sender, args) {
     sender.cancelUpload();
}

function onUploadComplete(sender, args) {
     sender.cancelUpload();
}
```

Web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*"
    path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
    type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

How am I to cancel an upload?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`confirmFileIsTooLarge()`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AjaxFileUpload#confirmfileistoolargefileitem) or [`validateFiles()`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/AjaxFileUpload#validatefilesfiles) methods to do this.